# How to find the most frequent categories?

Tags: r

I want to pick all categories with the highest frequencies & assign them to a new variable called `freq_cat`. The characters `a` and `b` are the most frequent in the following example. Can one help me, please?

```
exm <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","d"),
                  f=c(3,3,1,2))
```

The output I need is the following:

```
freq_cat: a b
```

Thank you!

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `exm %>% filter(f == max(f))`

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to subset `exm` on the condition that the column `f` is equal to the maximum of column `f`. Then you can select the column `"x"`.

```
exm[exm$f == max(exm$f),"x"]
[1] a b
Levels: a b c d
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach is via `which`, which checks for indices of a logical condition:

```
exm$x[which(exm$f==max(exm$f))]
[1] a b
Levels: a b c d
```